# Dualboot Angular13 and Angular1: cannot downgrade injectable services with parameters

Tags: angular, webpack, dependency-injection, webpack-5, angular13

I have dual boot with Angular 13 and Angular 1. The app is built with `webpack` v5. The `tsconfig` has key `"emitDecoratorMetadata":true`. After install I run NGCC on the NPM dependencies.

I cannot use downgraded v13 service with constructor parameters inside the v1 components.
The v13 services **without constructor parameters** are downgraded successfully.

- MyService.ts:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyV13Service {
    constructor(@Inject('DomSanitizer') private sanitizer: any) {
    }
}
```

- app.module.ts:

```
import angular from 'angular';
angular.module('MyV1Module', [
    ...
     ])
    .factory('MyV13Service', downgradeInjectable(MyV13Service))

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,UpgradeModule],
    providers: [
        MyV13Service,
        {provide: 'DomSanitizer', useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('DomSanitizer'), deps: ['$injector']}
    ]
...
})
export class AppModule {...}
```

I tried also:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyV13Service {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }
}
```

and:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,UpgradeModule],
    providers: [
        MyV13Service,
        {provide: DomSanitizer, useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('DomSanitizer'), deps: ['$injector']}
    ]
...
})
export class AppModule {...}
```

I tried also to import another dependency, like `Restangular`. 
Everything without success. In all cases I receive an error:

`Error: Error while instantiating injectable 'MyV13Service': This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid. This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator. Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.`

WIDW?

**[UPDATE]**: when I provide my service this way (with HttpClient dependency):
`providers:[{provide: MyV13Service, useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('MyV13Service'), deps: ['HttpClient']}]`

The error changes to:

```
Error: Error while instantiating injectable 'MyV13Service': R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MyV13Service -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at Object.factory (static.mjs:899:1)
```

When I add the `HttpClient` to the list of providers the error remains the same. Both `HttpClient` and `DomSanitizer` are not injectable.

**[UPDATE]**: the code is working when it is built with angular-cli. So, the problem here is in the webpack configuration.

Comment: You should be able to simply inject DomSanitizer without overriding the provider, since it is already provided via BrowserModule, and doesn't come from AngularJS. In short, "constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)" should be correct, if you remove the provider in your module.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work. What does it mean "if you remove the provider in your module"?

Comment: Within @NgModule, you've defined an AngularJS style provider for DomSanitizer. It starts with "{provide: DomSanitizer, useFactory: ...". As you are depending on DomSanitizer with an Angular service (and not an AngularJS service), you do not need to define such a provider.

Comment: When I define providers as `providers:[MyV13Service]` it fails with the same error `This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid`.